# Start a function through url

Tags: php, jquery

The following function is inside a page (mainpage.php) which I load dynamically into a tab (tabcontent.php) .

```
    $('.editlink').on('click', function() {

 var id = $(this).attr('data-ds');   
 $.ajax({
            url: 'noticejob.php?step=get&ds='+id,
            method: 'GET'
        }).success(function(response,status) {

            ...   
       });    
});
```

I call this function by this link, which is inside the tabcontent.php

```
<a href="#" data-ds="'.$val['DS'].'" data-target="#editmodal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-icon-only blue-madison tooltips editlink" data-placement="top" data-original-title="'.T::ACTIONS_6.'"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
```

All works fine.

Now I want to start this function over a url call for adding links into other pages to open the mainpage.php and start with this function (should open a modal).

For Example: mainpage.php?start=edit&ds=123

Is it possible and in which way?

Answer (score 0):

You can just print the JS you need to execute in the PHP page.

```
...
?>
<script>
$(function() {
    foo();
});
</script>
<?php
...
```

To open the modal automatically, either create a JS function that opens the modal and call it (with the previous method), or do

```
<script>
$(function() { $('.editlink').click(); });
</script>
```

Comment: What i have to do to call the new function by the url-query "mainpage.php?start=edit&ds=123" - start=edit?

Comment: Second think is, that i need the datas from the data-attributes from the normal link, how i can solve that part?

Comment: I try this, to call and start the "old" function but nothing happens
I catch the GET datas by php and create the following dynamic js-code and put it out...
"$(function() { 
      $(".editlink").click(); 
    });"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now it works,

i've put a new (named "edit_function") js function into the mainpage.php with the "old" code of the "$('.editlink').on('click', function() {..."

after that i call this function from the mainpage if there is a url parameter. I do it into the php file and create a dynamicaly js code

```
if($_GET['job']=='new')
{
  $p['JS']='edit_function("'.$_GET['detail'].'");';
}
```

at the other hand i call the function for the tabcontent.php page in this way

```
$('.editlink').on('click', function() {
 var id = $(this).attr('data-ds');   
 edit_function(id);
});
```

for me it works